# How to set an option to delete envelope in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

am in the process of understanding Docusign and API.

I am trying to achieve with docusign that I should have the document removed after x days and also the envelope.

I see a settings for document purge in the feature tabs.

But i am not seeing an option for deleting the sent envelope itself as i am taking the backup in my database myself.

Any reference to online material or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Document Retention" feature in DocuSign will purge documents from the DocuSign servers (for Completed, Declined, and Voided envelopes) N days after the envelope becomes Completed/Declined/Voided, where N is the number you specify in **Preferences > Features > Document Retention (link)**.  See page 31 of the Admin guide for details about this setting: https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/account-administration-reference-guide.pdf.

DocuSign retains Envelope-level information for all envelopes indefinitely -- even if you purge an envelope's documents.  This is done so that the transaction metadata (i.e., audit trail data like who it was sent to / when, what forms of authentication were used, who signed it / when, etc.) is always available should you need to prove the authenticity of the transaction at a later date.  So, you'll still see an Envelope listed in the **Sent Items** folder even after envelope documents are purged -- so that you can always access Envelope history and Certificate of Completion -- but if you open an Envelope after its documents have been purged, you'll simply see "placeholder" documents in place of what used to be the 'real' documents. (Each placeholder doc contains a one-sentence message to indicate that the original document no longer exists within DocuSign.)

Also, keep in mind that the "Document Retention" feature is an account-wide setting that will apply to all Envelopes sent through the account.  If you only want to purge documents for specific envelopes, you can do so via the API ("Purge Documents" operation).