# Deleting queued documents through the DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

We are currently in the process of developing a process to delete **select** completed documents from DocuSign. Through the API, I'm able to change the purgeState on the envelopes to either "documents_queued" or "documents_and_metadata_queued".

This queues the documents to be deleted in 14 days. However, since we don't have any retention set up globally, I'd like to test this to see what happens when the documents are actually deleted and how it might affect reporting. Is there a way to complete the deletion process through the API? It's not feasible to wait 14 days to complete the testing.

I've tried doing a DELETE from the resource below:

```
/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents
```

Response:

```
"errorCode": "ENVELOPE_INVALID_STATUS",
"message": "Invalid envelope status. Envelope status is not one of: Created, Sent, Delivered, Correct."
```

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The [DeleteDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/delete/) API call only works on **Draft** envelopes. So the response correctly indicates `ENVELOPE_INVALID_STATUS` as your envelope status is Completed.

---

From the retention policy [Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/articles/Document-Retention-What-you-should-know-before-using-this-feature)

> The 14-day purge queue duration is fixed, and cannot be changed. Therefore, if you enter a retention days value of '1' (one), then you are telling the system to purge the documents in 1 + 14 = 15 days.

You will have to use the [updateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) api to mark an envelope as purged

> When the purge request is initiated the envelope documents, or documents and envelope metadata, are placed in a purge queue for deletion in 14 days. A warning email notification is sent to the sender and recipients associated with the envelope, notifying them that the envelope documents will be deleted in 14 days and providing a link to the documents. A second email is sent 7 days later with the same message. At the end of the 14-day period, the envelope documents are deleted from the system.

---

See this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22718453/1219543)